# $\Pi^1_1$ relations have a $\Pi^1_1$ (skolem) choice function

Tags: logic, computability

There is a proof in the Ash/Knight book "Computable Structures and the Hyperarithmetical Hierarchy" Theorem 5.19 that states that if $Q$ is a $\Pi^1_1$-relation then $Q$ has a $\Pi^1_1$-(skolem) choice function $F$. See below:

For reference: $O$ -is Kleene's O, and $E^1_{\Sigma}$ kleene's $\Sigma^1_1$ enumeration relation.

Theorem 5.19: Let $Q$ be a $\Pi^1_1$ binary relation. Then there is a $\Pi^1_1$ function $F$ such that $F \subseteq Q$ and $\forall x [\exists y Q(x,y) \rightarrow Q(x,F(x))]$

Proof. Say $Q \leq_m O$ via $g$. For each $x$ we define $F(x)=y$ so that the ordinal $|g(x,y)|_O=\beta$ is as small as possible, and $y$ is the least such that $|g(x,y)|_O=\beta$.  By earlier theorems, there is a partial computable function $h$ such that for $u \in O$, $h(u)$ is a $\Sigma^1_1$ index for $\{v \in O : |v|_O \leq |u|_O \}$. Let $F(x)=y$ if and only if

(1) $Q(x,y)$

(2) $\forall z [ Q(x,z) \rightarrow E^1_{\Sigma}(h(g(x,z)), g(x,y)]$ $ \ $ (ensures $|g(x,y)|_O=\beta$ is as small as possible)

(3) $\forall z [ Q(x,z) \wedge E^1_{\Sigma}(h(g(x,y)),g(x,z))\rightarrow y \leq z )]$ $ \ $(ensures that $y$ is the least such that $|g(x,y)|=\beta$.)

It is clear from the definition that $F$ has all the desired properties. (END PROOF)

Here is how I see it:

1. Clearly this relation is $\Pi^1_1$ by definition.
2. Looking inside the brackets we have $[\neg Q(x,z) \vee E^1_{\Sigma}(h(g(x,z)),g(x,y)]$. Since $Q$ is $\Pi^1_1$ then $\neg Q$ is $\Sigma^1_1$, and since $E^1_{\Sigma}$ is $\Sigma^1_1$ whats inside the brackets is $\Sigma^1_1$.  Since $\forall z$ quantifies over natural numbers and not a function, thus the stipulation in (2) is $\Sigma^1_1$

Right away, since (1) is $\Pi^1_1$ and (2) is $\Sigma^1_1$ if they are satisfied together, this makes $F$ at least $\Delta^1_2$. What am I getting wrong?

Comment: For better readability and people who cannot use images, please consider adding the theorem in types form instead of image https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Ok I updated my original write-up to include a typed version of the proof.